# Turtle Graphics as a Haskell Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to implement [turtle graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics) in Haskell. The goal is to be able to write a function like this:

```
draw_something = do
    forward 100
    right 90
    forward 100
    ...
```

and then have it produce a list of points (maybe with additional properties):

```
> draw_something (0,0) 0        -- start at (0,0) facing east (0 degrees)
[(0,0), (0,100), (-100,100), ...]
```

I have all this working in a 'normal' way, but I've failed to implement it as a Haskell Monad and use the do-notation. The basic code:

```
data State a = State (a, a) a -- (x,y), angle
    deriving (Show, Eq)

initstate :: State Float
initstate = State (0.0,0.0) 0.0


-- constrain angles to 0 to 2*pi
fmod :: Float -> Float
fmod a 
    | a >= 2*pi = fmod (a-2*pi)
    | a <  0    = fmod (a+2*pi)
    | otherwise = a

forward :: Float -> State Float -> [State Float]
forward d (State (x,y) angle) = [State (x + d * (sin angle), y + d * (cos angle)) angle]

right :: Float -> State Float -> [State Float]
right d (State pos angle) = [State pos (fmod (angle+d))]


bind :: [State a] -> (State a -> [State a]) -> [State a]
bind xs f = xs ++ (f (head $ reverse xs))

ret :: State a -> [State a]
ret x = [x]
```

With this I can now write

```
> [initstate] `bind` (forward 100) `bind` (right (pi/2)) `bind` (forward 100)
[State (0.0,0.0) 0.0,State (0.0,100.0) 0.0,State (0.0,100.0) 1.5707964,State (100.0,99.99999) 1.5707964]
```

And get the expected result. However I can't make this an instance of `Monad`.

```
instance Monad [State] where
    ...
```

results in

```
`State' is not applied to enough type arguments
Expected kind `*', but `State' has kind `* -> *'
In the instance declaration for `Monad [State]'
```

And if I wrap the list in a new object

```
data StateList a = StateList [State a]

instance Monad StateList where
    return x = StateList [x]
```

I get

```
    Couldn't match type `a' with `State a'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for return :: a -> StateList a 
          at logo.hs:38:9
    In the expression: x        
    In the first argument of `StateList', namely `[x]'
    In the expression: StateList [x]
```

I tried various other versions but I never got it to run as I'd like to. What am I doing wrong? What do I understand incorrectly?

Comment: It ought to be possible to implement a turtlegraphics monad, growing a history of turtle positions and headings. But the way you're trying to implement a `Monad` instance confuses the type used to represent numbers in this history with the types of values in general. Your `ret` and `bind` concern computations which consider only states as values. But `return` and `>>=` should explain how to organise computations concerning values of any type, some of which might also extend the turtle's trail.

Comment: If you want the "monad" to generate a list of points then you may want Writer+State rather than State. Writer is typically the "monad of accumulation" though it can work in other ways. To progress you also need to look at why state monads are functions wrapped by a `newtype` - they are functions from current state to a pair of new state plus answer, not just new state. Often the answer is `unit` aka (). e.g forward would typically be `forward :: Float -> Turtle ()` assuming a monad called Turtle.

Answer (score 6):

The monad you're devising needs to have two type parameters. One for the saved trail (which will be fixed for a particular `do` sequence) and other for the results of computations.

You also need to think about how to compose two turtle-monadic values so that the binding operation is associative. For example,

```
right 90 >> (right 90 >> forward 100)
```

must be equal to

```
(right 90 >> right 90) >> forward 100
```

(and of course similarly for `>>=` etc.). This means that if you represent the turtle's history by a list of points, the binding operation most likely just cannot append the lists of points together; `forward 100` alone will result in something like `[(0,0),(100,0)]` but when it's prepended with rotation, the saved points need to be rotated too.

---

I'd say that the simplest approach would be to use the `Writer` monad. But I wouldn't save the points, I'd save just the actions the turtle performs (so that we don't need to rotate the points when combining the values). Something like

```
data Action = Rotate Double | Forward Double

type TurtleMonad a = Writer [Action] a
```

(This also means that we don't need to track the current direction, it's contained in the actions.) Then each of your functions just writes its argument into the `Writer`. And at the end, you can extract the final list from it and make a simple function that converts all the actions into a list of points:

```
track :: [Action] -> [(Double,Double)]
```

**Update:** Instead of using `[Action]` it would be better to use `Seq` from [Data.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html). It's also a [monoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html#t%3aMonoid) and [concatenating two sequences](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html#v%3a-62--60-) is very fast, it's amortized complexity is *O(log(min(n1,n2)))*, compared to *O(n1)* of `(++)`. So the improved type would be

```
type TurtleMonad a = Writer (Seq Action) a
```